# Getting Unexpected Error while accessing data form HortonBox Hadoop Hive server to tableau.?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, tableau-api

while am connecting Hive server to Tableau and then try to access data but getting Unexpected error.

**Error:**
[Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '40000' error message: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied. Principal [name=sandbox, type=USER] does not have following privileges on Object [type=TABLE_OR_VIEW, name=solomo.retail_store] : [SELECT]'.

Comment: At the risk of asking a silly question, does the "sandbox" user actually have select permissions on the solomo.retail_store table/view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer,First we will need to go to Hive and enter the Hive query

**Query**:grant SELECT on table "table-name" to user hue;

where “table” is the table you want user “hue” to view.